# Disable billing address for virtual products

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment, billing-address, virtual-products

I have a Magento 2.1.2 and I am using it to sell some products

My issue is not being able to place order on virtual products

Where I live, banks do not need the billing address when you are using a Visa/Mastercard for online purchases but I guess Magento requires it as a default rule for security

When users add virtual products and proceed to the checkout page and fill the payment fields, they cannot press on the “Place Order” button. However Physical products doesn’t have that issue

The picture below shows the fields and information required by users to fill when they are purchasing a virtual product

[image]

Comment: Is this a bug?  https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues

Comment: Don't think that its a bug because as i mentioned by default the billing address is required for security purposes but here banks do not require it

Comment: @Faezabdulkarem, if your banks don't require billing address, you can implement own payment method without billing address.

Comment: I am new to Magento so could you kindly link me to a tutorial

Comment: Did you find any solution for this ?